# Multiple return statements smells like what?

Tags: c#

Here's some code of mine that I don't like (this was my very first attempt at DI/IoC!). It's a small C# application that runs scheduled on one of our servers and is responsible for fetching the latest version of a VB6 codebase, compiling it and packaging an installer for it.

There's an `Execute` method in there that smells like... well *you tell me* what it smells like:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the build process.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Execute()
    {
        var errors = new List<string>();
        var logger = _logProvider.GetLogger(GetType().Name);

        DoArchiveOldInstallers(errors, logger);
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.StopOnBackupCurrentInstallerFailure && !DoBackupCurrentVersion(errors, logger))
        {
            OnExecutedCompleted(false);
            return;
        }

        if (Properties.Settings.Default.StopOnUpdateCodeBaseFailure && !DoGetLatestVersion(errors, logger))
        {
            OnExecutedCompleted(false);
            return;
        }

        if (Properties.Settings.Default.StopOnCompileFailure && !DoCompileCodeBase(errors, logger))
        {
            OnExecutedCompleted(false);
            return;
        }

        if (Properties.Settings.Default.StopOnBuildInstallerFailure && !DoBuildInstaller(errors, logger))
        {
            OnExecutedCompleted(false);
            return;
        }

        OnExecutedCompleted(true);
    }

    private void OnExecutedCompleted(bool success)
    {
        if (Completed != null) Completed(this, new CompletedEventArgs(success));
    }
```

---

#### Mea Culpa

Sorry this was posted like this. The conditions should read as follows:

```
if (!DoXXXXX(errors, logger) && !settings.StopOnXXXXXFailure)
```

This was a last-minute untested change I made just minutes prior to posting, without realizing it would totally mess up the method's logic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, I would question whether this code works correctly. Based on the names in your code, I assume that for example `DoCompileCodeBase()` should execute even when `StopOnCompileFailure` is `false`, but its result should be ignored. But that's not what happens: when `StopOnCompileFailure` is `false`, `DoCompileCodeBase()` doesn't even execute, because of short-circuiting evaluation of `&&`.

If what the code does is really what it should do (which is what I'm going to assume in the following text), then you should probably rename the settings properties.

Second, you can extract the checks and the `Do` method calls into a separate method (Simon's answer already suggested something similar):

```
// may need a better name
private bool ExecuteInternal()
{
    var errors = new List<string>();
    var logger = _logProvider.GetLogger(GetType().Name);
    var settings = Properties.Settings.Default;

    DoArchiveOldInstallers(errors, logger);

    if (settings.StopOnBackupCurrentInstallerFailure && !DoBackupCurrentVersion(errors, logger))
        return false;

    if (settings.StopOnUpdateCodeBaseFailure && !DoGetLatestVersion(errors, logger))
        return false;

    if (settings.StopOnCompileFailure && !DoCompileCodeBase(errors, logger))
        return false;

    if (settings.StopOnBuildInstallerFailure && !DoBuildInstaller(errors, logger))
        return false;

    return true;
}

public override void Execute()
{
    bool success = ExecuteInternal();
    OnExecutedCompleted(success);
}
```

Third, since all the `Do` methods are on the same object, you could change `errors` and `logger` into fields, so that you don't have to pass them around. Though I'm not completely convinced this is actually better, especially if `Execute()` is a method that's called over and over.

Fourth, you might consider associating all the settings properties with the right `Do` method using some kind of data structure:

```
private readonly Tuple<bool, Func<bool>>[] action;

// in constructor:
actions = new Tuple<bool, Func<bool>>[]
{
    new Tuple<bool, Func<bool>>(settings.StopOnBackupCurrentInstallerFailure, DoBackupCurrentVersion),
    new Tuple<bool, Func<bool>>(settings.StopOnUpdateCodeBaseFailure, DoGetLatestVersion),
    new Tuple<bool, Func<bool>>(settings.StopOnCompileFailure, DoCompileCodeBase),
    new Tuple<bool, Func<bool>>(settings.StopOnBuildInstallerFailure, DoBuildInstaller)
}

private bool ExecuteInternal()
{
    var errors = new List<string>();
    var logger = _logProvider.GetLogger(GetType().Name);
    var settings = Properties.Settings.Default;

    DoArchiveOldInstallers();

    foreach (var action in actions)
    {
        if (action.Item1 && !action.Item2())
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The syntax to initialize the list of `Tuple`s is not great. You could improve that by having a special type `TupleList<T1, T2> : List<Tuple<T1, T2>>`, which would have a method like `void Add(T1 item1, T2 item2)`. That way, the initialization simplifies to:

```
actions = new TupleList<bool, Func<bool>>
{
    { settings.StopOnBackupCurrentInstallerFailure, DoBackupCurrentVersion },
    { settings.StopOnUpdateCodeBaseFailure, DoGetLatestVersion },
    { settings.StopOnCompileFailure, DoCompileCodeBase },
    { settings.StopOnBuildInstallerFailure, DoBuildInstaller }
}
```

The next step after this could be encapsulating each action into its own object, so that you could do something like:

```
foreach (var action in actions)
{
    if (!action.Execute())
        return false;
}
```

And each action would be responsible for checking the right setting, if appropriate. (Actions that don't do any checks, like `DoArchiveOldInstallers` could be represented by a different type that inherits from the same base, or something like that.) But I'm not sure doing that would be worth it in this case.

Comment: BTW, I also considered using calling `OnExecutedCompleted()` once in a `finally`, but I think that would be an abuse of the feature.

Comment: Upvote in 6 hours... I apologize for the stupid bug, that was a last-minute change that I did just minutes prior to posting, hadn't even tested it and I feel as stupid as the bug itself...

Comment: Your answers covered it all I believe, well done!

Comment: I think I'd rather have a `Dictionary<bool, Func<bool>>` than a `Tuple<bool, Func<bool>>[]`. Wow you guys don't see it, but the rest of this code is so ugly, it's unreal! Can't believe I wrote that crap less than 6 months ago!

Comment: @retailcoder Nope, `Dictionary` wouldn't work here, because it could have only one `Func` for `true` and one for `false`.

Comment: Ok now I got it right: `return executionSteps.All(executionStep => executionStep.Item2() || !executionStep.Item1);` (off a `var executionSteps = new List<Tuple<bool, Func<bool>>>{...}`)

Comment: @retailcoder Yeah, I considered something like that. But I think that in this case, the `foreach` is clearer. LINQ works best for *queries*, i.e. when there are no side effects.

Comment: As for *what type of smell?*  The code smells of **REPETITION** and **RIGIDITY**.  Both covered nicely by the rewrites suggested.

Answer (score 6):

First thing I noticed, I do not like the `Do` in the function names. For instance, in `DoArchiveOldInstallers` there are two verbs.  The idea is to mimic english, I never say "Do go for a run" when I'm talking to people.  The code should be the same.  `ArchiveOldInstallers` works perfectly well, and the verb describing what is going on is still there.

Second, the if statements get a little confusing.  I'm not sure what to do with them right now, but they need to be changed.

Other than that, the white space, capitalization, and formatting look good.

Answer (score 3):

I would create a helper method for returning the value you want to give to `OnExecutedCompleted`, and also store the value of `Properties.Settings.Default` in a variable.

```
bool TodoRenameMeToWhatYouThinkSuitsYou()
{
    SomeType settings = Properties.Settings.Default;
    if (settings.StopOnBackupCurrentInstallerFailure && !DoBackupCurrentVersion(errors, logger))
       return false;
    if (settings.StopOnUpdateCodeBaseFailure && !DoGetLatestVersion(errors, logger)) 
       return false;
    if (settings.StopOnCompileFailure && !DoCompileCodeBase(errors, logger))
       return false;
    if (settings.StopOnBuildInstallerFailure && !DoBuildInstaller(errors, logger)) 
       return false;
    return true;
}
```

Then you can replace the smelly part in your original method with

```
OnExecutedCompleted(TodoRenameMeToWhatYouThinkSuitsYou());
```

*(I apoligize for not following the coding conventions in this answer, I am not a C# developer)*

Comment: I don't think `executeIsCompleted` is a good name for that method, because it doesn't just test whether execution is complete, it also performs the execution itself.

Comment: Smells like Java code :) (sees edit and LOL!)

Comment: @svick I agree, as I currently can't come up with a better name, I renamed it to `todoRenameMeToWhatYouThinkSuitsYou` (I didn't put much thought into the naming of the method as that wasn't the most important part of the question)

Comment: @retailcoder Java code doesn't smell (at least not my code :P). I hope this solves the multiple return statements for you though.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg yes it does: you can tell because you haven't named it `TodoRenameMeToWhatYouThinkSuitsYou()` :)

Comment: @retailcoder That better? :)

Comment: Also, `obj` is a very bad name for a variable. I would use something like `settings`.